# Sitecore item:setdefaultworkflow and item:resetdefaultworkflow commands

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

I am Using Sitecore 6.6 
I believe  item:setdefaultworkflow and item:resetdefaultworkflow commands are used to reset the workflow fields on an Item with values set on Standard values. 
If not please correct me.
Here is the Path in Core:
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Workflow/Set Default Workflow

commands are not shown on the Ribbon. How do I use these commands? what is their purpose. Any Help is greatly appreciated.

I am aware of Version >> Fields(Reset)>> then choose the fields to reset with multiple clicks.
I am trying to use these commands if they solve my purpose to reset the Workflow Fields to standard values with a command on Review Tab >> Workflow section with one Click.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, these buttons are only visible on `__Standard Values` items.  They are used to assign the workflow that will be used for new versions of that template going forward, or to clear the workflow that has been set (note that items which are already part way through a workflow will still need to finish it before they are no longer associated with a workflow).

The idea is that you assign the workflow to the standard values of templates (or base templates) in your solution, and those settings then get carried through to your content items.

Although you are able to, I'd advise against fiddling with the workflow fields on individual items before you fully understand the purpose of the fields.

For more information, I'd suggest looking at the Sitecore workflow reference document: https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/workflow_reference_sc60orlater-a4.pdf